# Having trouble remoting into Sitecore with Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I’m trying to hit the Sitecore Webservices with the following Script:

The following function comes from `Sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/Platform/Functions/Remoting`

```
function Set-SitecoreConfiguration {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$SitecoreHost,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$User,

        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Password
    )
    $URI = $SitecoreHost + "/sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteAutomation.asmx";
    $GLOBAL:SpeRemoteProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI
    $GLOBAL:SpeRemoteUser = $User;
    $GLOBAL:SpeRemotePassword = $Password;
} 

#Connect to SiteCore utilizing function above
Set-SitecoreConfiguration –SitecoreHost 'http://sitecorehostname' -User 'Admin' –Password 'b'
```

This fails with a 404. As you can see, the final URI is:

http://sitecorehostname/sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteAutomation.asmx, which actually does exist in the directory structure of the website.

One directive that sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io tells you to do is to update the following in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteCoreSite\Website\App_Config\Include\Cognifide.Powershell.config:

(https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/security.html)

```
<sitecore>
  <powershell>
    <services>
      <restfulv1 enabled="true" />
      <restfulv2 enabled="true" />
      <remoting enabled="true" />
      <fileDownload enabled="true" />
      <fileUpload enabled="true" />
      <mediaDownload enabled="true" />
      <mediaUpload enabled="true" />
      <handleDownload enabled="true " />
      <client enabled="true" />
      <execution enabled="true" />
    </services>
  </powershell>
</sitecore>
```

Even so, I get the following Powershell error:

> New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not
>   Found. At C:\Scripts\SitecoreConnectionPOC.ps1:17 char:30
>   +     $GLOBAL:SpeRemoteProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI
>   +                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (http://sitecorehostname...Automation.asmx:Uri) [New-WebServiceProxy],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy

Any idea what the issue might be? Do we need to enable some sort of capability in Sitecore? I have SPE installed, fyi.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Crossposting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465699/having-trouble-remoting-into-sitecore-with-powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the version of the script stored in SPE is out of date. I'd prefer you not use it anyways.

First download and install the SPE Remoting module from the marketplace; last one in the list.

[image: Remoting Download]

Setup instructions on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGvT8eDdWrg).

Then run this script.

```powershell
Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri https://remotesitecore
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        // Do something remotely
}
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

[Helpful link to book for remoting](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting.html)

Comment: Thank you, Michael! I'll follow these steps, but I have a quick question. I went to https://marketplace.sitecore.net/ and typed in SPE Remoting in the module search field and nothing was returned. Am I in the wrong place?

Comment: It's actually a download available for Sitecore PowerShell Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving a 404 message in Powershell ISE within Sitecore. When I looked at my Sitecore log file I could see some nested exceptions including these lines

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: The file '/sitecore modules/powershell/services/404.htm' does not exist.
Source: System.Web
```

There was a `web.config` in the `sitecore modules\PowerShell\Services` directory which included these lines

```
<!-- Alternative to disabling the Documentation protocol -->
      <!-- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tyf2t8t(v=vs.100).aspx -->
      <wsdlHelpGenerator href="404.htm"/>
```

Commenting out the wsdlHelpGenerator line resolved my issue, I was also able to access `sitecore%20modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteAutomation.asmx` directly via the browser.